# Bootstrap 5 carousel of multiple items overlap and active slide larger than previous and next slide

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I need a carousel based on [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abQpy.png). my code below is only showing every active slide. Any idea how to adjust the size of the active slide and a little bit smaller for previous and next slide and overlaps with each other so that the active slide is at the center?
tia

```html
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide mt-5 mx-3" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                                          <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>/girl-player.jpg" alt="First slide">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="carousel-item">
                                          <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>/pixel-player.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="carousel-item">
                                          <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>/pixel-player.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Here are some 3d demos of carousels using only css and js and html https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/gRJWqm